# What is the effect of explicitly specifying a generic apply method's type?

Tags: scala, generics

It's not very clear to me how adding a a Type parameter to a generic object can influence the call of its apply method. If that didn't make much sense, I have tried to formulate a simple example to express my trivial confusion.

```
scala> object Foo {def apply[T] = "Hello from foo"}
object Foo    

scala> Foo
val res0: Foo.type = Foo$@709d6de5

scala> Foo[Int]
val res1: String = Hello from foo
```

Why is it only that when I specify `[Int]`, the apply method is called, and returns "Hello from foo"

On the other hand, when I use an apply method that takes a parameter, I don't need to specify the type anymore.

```
scala> object Bar {def apply[T](useless: T) = "Hello from bar"}
object Bar

scala> Bar
val res2: Bar.type = Bar$@33089426

scala> Bar("Something useless")
val res3: String = Hello from bar
```

Why in the first case (when there were no parameters) I had to specify the type, while in the second case (when there was one useless parameter) I did not have to specify the type, for the apply to be called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler needs to know when you're referring to the `object` and when you're invoking the `apply()` method. It uses `[]` and/or `()` as the clue.

If you add an empty value parameter list to the `Foo.apply` then you can drop the `[Int]` specification.

```
scala> object Foo {def apply[T]() = "Hello from foo"}
defined object Foo

scala> Foo
res25: Foo.type = Foo$@332d4c4f

scala> Foo[Int]
res26: String = Hello from foo

scala> Foo()
res27: String = Hello from foo
```

If your `apply` takes no parameters, type or value, then the only way to invoke it is to specify it completely.

```
cala> object Baz {def apply = "Hello from Baz"}
defined object Baz

scala> Baz                                                                   
res14: Baz.type = Baz$@5bd4ecec

scala> Baz()                                                                 
<console>:13: error: Baz.type does not take parameters
       Baz()
          ^

scala> Baz.apply                                                             
res16: String = Hello from Baz
```